# Check if system is causal

Tags: real-analysis, signal-processing

[image]

I am a little confused on attached question. For t=1, g(t) =g(1), requires integration upto t=2, which is in future...So how can it be causal? Is it a typo (not causal)?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you. This is not causal.

It looks like a typo. Or perhaps someone fell into the trap of blindly applying the criterion ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system#cite_note-1)):

> A necessary and sufficient condition for a system to be causal,
>   regardless of linearity, is: the impulse response of the system must use
>   only the present and past values of the input to determine the output.

That is, that $h(t)=0$ for $t<0$. Indeed, if we attempt to obtain the impulse response $h(t)$ of this system by computing the output of a Dirac delta, as $g(t)=\mathcal{R}(\delta(t))$, we get a [step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), which corresponds to a causal system.
But this is wrong, because the system is [not time-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-variant_system), hence it does not have an impulse response (or, if you prefer, it depends on two time indexes).

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful

Comment: You're welcome. I see that you have many questions asked, but none accepted. Perhaps you should read here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers